# Automated Website Testing/Sanity/Quality

Tags: javascript, html, css, testing

I am thinking about building a tool that starts from the root of a webpage and traverses the entire website gathering a list of resources such as CSS/HTML/Javascript files and then runs CSS/Javascript Lint + HTML Validator + Broken Link Finder. Before I start building something like this, I was wondering if this exists already?

Thanks.

I already searched Google quite a bit and couldn't find much.

Comment: There are tools that do some of what you specify but I find them not useful. Either my site is small enough that I can run through the checks one by one on the various sites or else my site is so large that the check everything tool gets bogged down and takes hours to run.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd be the first if you made a package that can

- Scan a web site for resources
- Validate HTML
- Validate CSS
- Validate JS
- Find Broken Links

I can think of a couple of ways to do some of those.

You might be able to use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) or other website copier to **scan for resources**.

**HTML validation** could be done with this tool: [WDG HTML Validator](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/) (has a *Validate Entire Site* option)

There's a Microsoft plugin for IIS - [Search Engine Optimization Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/download/SEOToolkit), it can scan a given site for **broken links** (along with several other pretty nifty site stats)

Can't think of any that will validate CSS and JS while scanning an entire site, modern web design practices usually yield a small number of JS/CSS files anyway so you may be fine one-offing those in some circumstances.  I can see potential for a need to scan inline JS/CSS though.

---

To assist you in developing such a tool you could download the source for

**W3C Markup-Validator**: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/markup-validator/

**CSS Lint**: https://github.com/stubbornella/csslint

**JS Lint**: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this link helps:
[Website check](http://uitest.com/en/check/)

You can check:

- Accessibility
- Validation (for example W3C)
- Miscellaneous (for example links)
- Show (Http response / WHOIS)
- Estimate (Website traffice)
- Website Analysis

Perhaps it would be easy to make an offline .Net application to include all these links into one application.

Regards